# Hacer un espiral con canvas

Tags: android, canvas

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde hago un circulo pero quiero coonvertirlo en espiral. ayuda esto no es un meme

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
        Lienzo fondo = new Lienzo(this);
        layout1.addView(fondo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class Lienzo extends View {

        public Lienzo(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawRGB(255, 255, 255);
            int ancho = canvas.getWidth();
            int alto = canvas.getHeight();
            Paint pincel1 = new Paint();
            pincel1.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
            pincel1.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            for (int f = 0; f < 10; f++) {
                int a=ancho/2;
                int h=alto/3;
                canvas.drawCircle(a-40 , h-80, f * 20, pincel1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Me falto aclarar que estoy usando java android y no android studio

Answer (score 1):

Solo debes girar el angulo 180 grados. Te recomiendo que leas un poco sobre fibonacci también para entender como hacer una espiral perfecta de manera sencilla y muy comprensible.

```
 int x = getSize().width / 2 - 10;
        int y = getSize().height/ 2 - 10;
        int width = 20;
        int height = 20;
        int startAngle = 0;
        int arcAngle = 180;
        int depth = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                //   g.drawArc(x + 10, y + 10, width, height, startAngle + 10, -arcAngle);
                //  x = x - 5;
                y = y - depth;
                width = width + 2 * depth;
                height = height + 2 * depth;
                g.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, -arcAngle);
            } else {
                //  g.drawArc(x + 10, y + 10, width, height, startAngle + 10, arcAngle);
                x = x - 2 * depth;
                y = y - depth;
                width = width + 2 * depth;
                height = height + 2 * depth;
                g.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, arcAngle);
            }
        }
```

[REFERENCIA ORIGINAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29638733/java-draw-a-circular-spiral-using-drawarc)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ahora tengo un problema con el getSize me marca como invalido

Comment: Manuel, Esta respuesta es para Java swing , NO aplica para android.